# Function to compare a column with a series Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to use a functiom to compare values from a column of a dataframe to a series.

I want to check if a value of that column is inside that series.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel ('FS.xlsx',sep=";",na_values="Ninguno",encoding='latin1')


a=pd.Series(['7401','7403','7394','4404'],
              name="vals")


a=a.to_frame()

df['Centro']=df['Centro'].apply(str)


def seccion (row):
    if row['Centro'].isin(a['vals'])==True  and row['Almacén']=='EW01':
        return 'Ventas'


df['Sector']=df.apply(seccion,axis=1)
```

I'm receiving as a result 'str' object has no attribute 'isin'

Also I'va tried to use the following:

```
    if row.apply(lambda x: (row['Centro'] in a['vals']))==True  and row['Almacén']=='EW01':
        return 'Ventas'
```

And I'm receiving as a result The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

```
df.head().to_dict() :

{'Referencia': {0: '9000126531',
  1: '9000126540',
  2: '9000126784',
  3: '9000126853',
  4: '9000126304'},
 'Material': {0: 3140401570900.0,
  1: 3140401570900.0,
  2: 3140401570900.0,
  3: 3140401570900.0,
  4: 3140401570900.0},
 'Lote': {0: 'F', 1: 'F', 2: 'F', 3: 'F', 4: 'F'},
 'Texto breve de material': {0: 'TECLADO HP USB SMART CARD BLACK',
  1: 'TECLADO HP USB SMART CARD BLACK',
  2: 'TECLADO HP USB SMART CARD BLACK',
  3: 'TECLADO HP USB SMART CARD BLACK',
  4: 'TECLADO HP USB SMART CARD BLACK'},
 'Centro': {0: '7404', 1: '7404', 2: '7404', 3: '7404', 4: '7404'},
 'Almacén': {0: '0001', 1: '0001', 2: '0001', 3: '0001', 4: '0001'},
 'Clase de movimiento': {0: 641, 1: 641, 2: 641, 3: 641, 4: 641},
 'Texto de clase de movimiento': {0: 'TR A stock tránsito',
  1: 'TR A stock tránsito',
  2: 'TR A stock tránsito',
  3: 'TR A stock tránsito',
  4: 'TR A stock tránsito'},
 'Elemento PEP': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 'Documento material': {0: 4903632156,
  1: 4903632157,
  2: 4903632934,
  3: 4903632953,
  4: 4903631823},
 'Posición doc.mat.': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1},
 'Fe.contabilización': {0: Timestamp('2022-01-26 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2022-01-26 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2022-01-26 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2022-01-26 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2022-01-26 00:00:00')},
 'Ctd.en UM entrada': {0: -1, 1: -1, 2: -1, 3: -1, 4: -1},
 'Un.medida de entrada': {0: 'UN', 1: 'UN', 2: 'UN', 3: 'UN', 4: 'UN'},
 'Doc.Mat. FI': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 'Pedido': {0: 8000094647.0,
  1: 8000094652.0,
  2: 8000094881.0,
  3: 8000094927.0,
  4: 8000094420.0},
 'Posición': {0: 10, 1: 10, 2: 10, 3: 10, 4: 10},
 'Nombre del usuario': {0: '933514',
  1: '933514',
  2: '933514',
  3: '933514',
  4: '933514'},
 'UM precio pedido': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 'Importe ML': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
 'Sector': {0: 'FS', 1: 'FS', 2: 'FS', 3: 'FS', 4: 'FS'}}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You can do this instead in your seccion function condition: if row['Centro'] in a['vals'] 
 and row['Almacén'] == 'EW01':

Comment: If you add a working data example, it will be easier to help :)

Comment: I think it should work if you replace the "if" condition with `(row['Centro'].isin(a['vals']) & row['Almacén']=='EW01').any()`. That said, it would be helpful if you could show us what the data looks like. For instance, it would be helpful if you could paste the result of `df.head().to_dict()` into your question.

Comment: Just pasted  df.head().to_dict()

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel ('FS.xlsx',sep=";",na_values="Ninguno",encoding='latin1')

a=pd.Series(['7401','7403','7394','4404'], name="vals")

df['Sector'] = (df['Centro'].astype(str).isin(a) & (df['Almacén']=='EW01')).map({True: 'Ventas'})
```

The last line performs the two checks and assign a value between `True` / `False` to each row depending on the result of the checks. We can then use `map` to replace `True` with `'Ventas'` and the rest with `np.nan`.